# How to make a python encryption program?

Tags: python, encryption

I need to store a password of servers in my application in a encryption which I need in a text form for later use. Is it possible to do this in python and how? Please explain.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because you didn't ask the question (how do I write an encryption algorithm) that you wanted the answer to (What encryption algorithm should I use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do NOT write your own encryption/decryption algorithm unless it's for personal curiosity. Cryptography has a lot of very difficult aspects to it, and getting even one wrong means that you have 0 security.

In addition, before using cryptographic functionality, study it a bit to ensure you are using it correctly. For instance, do NOT store passwords in an encryption that is reversible - you don't need the plain text of the password. You want to use a one-way encryption on it (called a cryptographic hash), and compare it against a cryptographic hash of what the user inputs. If they match, then let them in. Now the database has no trace of the original password, as hashing cannot be reversed*.

( It doesn't stop there, though - you also want the hashing algorithm to be 'slow' so that a cracker has to try their thousands of different attempts very slooowly but legitimate usage will get it in a few tries anyway. To make hashing 'slow' you need an algorithm like bcrypt which has a tunable parameter for how slow it should be, so it is even future proof. )

http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypto.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto

*Except with a rainbow table, which is where a would-be cracker computes in advance the result of hashing every common password. To protect against this, combine the password with a salt before hashing it, and store the salt with the user.

Comment: No no no, I need to the plain text of password for later use. I need to ssh to the server using the plain text password.

Comment: @user2032220 Ok, then use AES and be very careful that no one else can get access to the key you use for AES but you. (For a start, it should be stored in some place that is denied read access for every account except yours, etc)

Comment: Yeah AES is my best bet. I need the key in the program itself. Where should I put the key?

Comment: @user2032220 Don't forget that the key doesn't necessarily have to be in the program itself - it could be in a private file, it could be in a system variable, and maybe I am missing some other ideas too. But wherever you put it, if anyone else is able to read the key for whatever reason, you instantly have no security.

Comment: Okay. I will put the key in the private file! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Or another trick, I generated random key with 32 cipher object.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)'s implementation of AES.